# iPhone images rotate 90 degrees when using cloudinary

Tags: node.js, iphone, image, rotation, cloudinary

I use Cloudinary for my blog site (built with node js).
My problem is that when I upload an image from an iPhone, it rotates 90 degrees. I have already tried `angle: "ignore"` but this does not seem to work. I think it has to do with the exif information. How do I get rid of it or am I using the wrong cloudinary parameters?
(also does not work when I include a_ignore in the url)

Here is the upload code:

`let result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {resource_type: type, angle:"ignore"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by recommending to remove `angle: "ignore"` from the upload call parameters, try to upload again, and then you probably experience one of the following cases:

1. The original may not have any embedded rotation metadata and therefore there's no way to know what's the correct rotation.
2. The original may have the rotation metadata, and the delivery URL was of the original, which by default sends the original image, as is, without any Cloudinary processes. So far so good, however, at that point, it's up to the client/device to be responsible to parse the metadata and render it correctly by the rotation metadata, and unfortunately, there are indeed cases of clients "ignoring" the rotation metadata when rendering images.
3. The image was both rotated manually AND the metadata wasn't stripped, which may result in an extra (unnecessary) rotation.

After you check which case you think you might be on, here are some possible ways to fix:

- For case #1 - In case you have access to the original unrotated and un-metadata-stripped version of the image, try to upload that one again instead.
- For case #2 - On delivery, instead of using the original image's delivery URL, try to use a derived version of it (e.g., add `q_auto` to the URL as a transformation). Using any of Cloudinary's transformations will automatically optimize the image before delivery, but importantly for this case, it'll also rotate the image by the rotation metadata info (assuming it has one), and last but not least, will strip the metadata, so it'll always show the image by the intended rotation.
- For case #3 - Usually a possible fix for this is to indeed add `angle: "ignore"`, which is, as mentioned previously, recommended as a delivery transformation (`a_ignore` in the URL) rather than as part of the upload parameters.

If you could share the original image here, I'll be happy to take a closer look and offer solutions. If privacy is an issue, share it with [Cloudinary's support team](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) who will be happy to assist.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just needed to delete `angle: "ignore"` from the upload parameter. Now it seems to work.